# Request does not come to ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, request

I made a dynamic permanent list with data from the server, did it like his ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eENDlIgadr4)), but my code does not reach the request (Future fetch () .....), tell me, what's the problem? How do I still send a request?

My code -

```
class Report extends StatelessWidget {
  static String? res = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Numeric Keyboard Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var ressultat = json.decode(MyApp.resultat)['Transactions'];
  // final controller = ScrollController();
  // bool hasMore = true;
  // int page = 2;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      if(controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
        fetch();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
 //HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE HERE
  Future fetch() async {
    var url = "http://10.0.101.141:1515/api/Transaction/gettransactions";
    print(url);
    var token = LoginClass.resJson;
    final limit = 5;

    try {
      final response = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(url),
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
          },
          body: json.encode({
            "Filters": {
              "DateFrom": MyApp.dateFrom,
              "DateTo": MyApp.dateEnd,
              "SumFrom": MyApp.sumFrom,
              "SumTo": MyApp.sumTo,
              "WalletId": null,
              "ClientPhoneNum": MyApp.phoneNum},
            "Sorting": {
              "Field": "Amount",
              "Order": "desc"},
            "Pagination":{
              "PageNumber": page,
              "PageSize": limit
            }

          })
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var reportResult = (response.body);
        print(MyApp.resultat);
        final List ress = json.decode(reportResult)['Transactions'];
        setState(() {
          page++;

          if(MyApp.rowNumber!.length < limit && MyApp.walletName!.length < limit && MyApp.payerPhoneNumber!.length < limit && MyApp.createdDate!.length < limit && MyApp.amount!.length < limit) {
            hasMore = false;
          }

          MyApp.rowNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final rowNumber = item['RowNumber'].toString();
            return rowNumber;
          }));
          MyApp.walletName?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final walletName = item['WalletName'].toString();
            return walletName;
          }));
          MyApp.payerPhoneNumber?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final phoneNumber = item['PayerPhoneNumber'].toString();
            return phoneNumber;
          }));
          MyApp.createdDate?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final createdDate = item['CreatedDate'].toString();
            return createdDate;
          }));
          MyApp.amount?.addAll(ress.map<String>((item) {
            final amount = item['Amount'].toString();
            return amount;
          }));
        });



        print(MyApp.createdDate.runtimeType);
      } else {
        var res = response.statusCode;
        print(res);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }

  }

  final controller = ScrollController();
  bool hasMore = true;
  int page = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Column (
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2, 20, 2, 2),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      width: 500,
                      child:  Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Text('№'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Text('Дата'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Text('Кошелек'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                child: Text('Сумма'),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    Container(
                        width: 500,
                        height: 650,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: controller,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            itemCount: MyApp.rowNumber!.length + 1,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              if (index < MyApp.rowNumber!.length)  {
                                 return Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                            children: [
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Text(' ${MyApp.rowNumber?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    width: 80,
                                                    child:  Text('${MyApp.createdDate?[index].replaceFirst(RegExp('T'), '')}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text('${MyApp.walletName?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                        Text('${MyApp.payerPhoneNumber?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Container(
                                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                    child: Text('${MyApp.amount?[index]}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )

                                );
                              } else {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: hasMore
                                        ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                                        : const Text('Список полностью загружен')
                                  ,),
                                );
                              }

                            }
                        )
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => context.go('/home'), child: Text('Назад'))
                  ]),

            ),

          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry, I probably added a lot of redundant code, but that's because I don't know what code exactly you need to see (((

Comment: Maybe this bug from  if (response.statusCode == 200) {} in fetch(). Try to add "return ress;" under  print(MyApp.createdDate.runtimeType);

Comment: If u can't fix, u can up code to Github and I'll help u fix it

Comment: @BobLee Can you point out exactly where?
And let me remind you that the code does not reach Future....

Comment: [If I upload the code like this, can you help me?](https://dpaste.org/UE0EJ)

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetch();
  }

and remove Future => just only fetch()
Let's try

Comment: I can't run your code so I don't know exactly

Comment: @BobLee Wow, now I have two pages displayed, but unfortunately it does not go any further. We are on the right track 
`@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetch();}` - now my code looks like this

Comment: If u use Future u need add return to return data

Comment: @BobLee What exactly do I need to return? Sorry, I'm not thinking at all, I spent the whole day on this

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was solved by itself, I returned my code back